# Discrete Time Fourier Transform result. Is it correct?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have calculated the Discrete Time Fourier Transform of the function $x(n)=(1/4)^{n}u(n+4)$ (where $u$ is the Unit Step function) and the result I came up with is:

\begin{equation}
X(\omega)=\frac{1024 \cdot e^{4i\omega}}{4-e^{-i\omega}}
\end{equation}

Is the result right or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks right to me: 
$$\sum_{n=-4}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^ne^{-i\omega n}
= \left(\frac{1}{4}e^{-i\omega}\right)^{-4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n}e^{-i\omega n} = (4e^{i\omega})^4\left(\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{4}e^{-i\omega}}\right)$$
which is the same as what you wrote, if my mental arithmetic is to be believed.

Comment: Yes that is another form of my solution before doing all the calculations. Thanks!